# Next.js problems with sharing data between scripts

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state, react-component, openweathermap

I'm trying to develop weather app based on weather `API`, but I've noticed, that I totaly don't know how to share data or state between two or more different scripts\components. I have component `CardList` and inside this component I fetch my data from `OpenWeather` `API`. Here it is code:

```js
import { CardListProps } from "./CardList.props";
import styles from "./CardList.module.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card } from "../Card/Card";
import { API_KEY } from './settings';


export const CardList = ({ children, ...props }: CardListProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);



    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(setData);
    }, []);

    if (!data) return null;
    console.log(data)
    const { name, weather, main, wind, clouds } = data; //destructing of obj
    const { description, icon } = weather[0];
    const { temp, humidity, feels_like, pressure } = main;
    const { speed } = wind;
    const { all } = clouds;

    return (
        <div
            className={styles.CardList}
            {...props}
        >
            <Card name="Wind Speed" info={parseFloat(speed.toFixed(2))+'km/h'}></Card>
            <Card name="Clouds" info={all + '%'}></Card>
            <Card name="Pressure" info={pressure + ' hpa'}></Card>
            <Card name="Humidity" info={humidity + '%'}></Card>
        </div>  
    )
};
```

And here below screenshot how it looks like:

[image]

And as you see it works for me, but for example if I want to send for example from my `<Search />` component with input state (name of city), I don't know how to do that.

Here below my `<Input />` code:

```js
import { InputProps } from "./Input.props";
import styles from "./Input.module.css";
import cn from 'classnames'
import { useState } from "react";


export const Input = ({ className, ...props }: InputProps): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <input className={cn(className, styles.input)} {...props} />
    );
};
```

And here below `<Search />` component with `<Input />` and `<Button>` code:

```js
import { SearchProps } from "./Search.props";
import styles from "./Search.module.css";
import cn from 'classnames';
import { Input } from "../Input/Input";
import { Button } from "../Button/Button";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import GlassIcon from './glass.svg';


import { cookies } from "../../libs/setCookie";

export const Search = ({ className, ...props }: SearchProps): JSX.Element => {

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("");
    const [citiesList, setCitiesList] = useState([]);

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        setCitiesList((currentArray) => [...currentArray, inputValue])
    }

    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className={cn(className, styles.search)} {...props} >
            <Button
                appearance="ghost"
                className={styles.button}
                onClick={handleOnClick}
            >
                <GlassIcon />
            </Button>
            <Input
                className={styles.input}
                placeholder="Search location here"
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={handleOnChange}

            />
        </div>
    )
};
```

I would really thankful if you help me:)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify to which component you want to send the state value(city name). And also you should mention the name of the component for each component you have posted like **input.js** for input component if that is the name you are using.

Comment: You can either [lift the input state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common parent component of both `CardList` and `Search` and pass it down to them, or use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to hold the input state and pass it to each component via context.